# All available load balancers have exceeded maximum rule limit 148

Tags: azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

We are not able to provision a new namespace because we have this error message: all available load balancers have exceeded maximum rule limit 148

```
Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service dev-mars50/ingress-nginx: selectLoadBalancer: cluster(kubernetes) service(dev-mars50/ingress-nginx) isInternal(true) - all available load balancers have exceeded maximum rule limit 148, vmSetNames ([agentpool-availabilitySet-30450843])
```

Comment: I also received this error when creating a new service with an external IP in kubernetes services. But AZ tech team's reply is just a random guess. Can't determine the issue yet. Did you already fix this one @christophe-chirat ?

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket from Microsoft and it was discovered a bug.

In the Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#load-balancer it is indicated that the rule limit per resource for a basic LB is 250.
It would appear that the limit was configured with a lower value.

A pull request has been made to increase the default limit https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/76487

Answer (score 0):

Limits are described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#load-balancer

its kinda weird it says 148, i think 150 is the limit, but nonetheless, not much you can do.

rework your services\ingress structure.

You can create a second worker type and that would have separate loadbalancer, but I dont think thats supported with AKS, yet.